# cordova-plugin-inappbrowser interferes with tel: and sms:

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I'm on Cordova 7 and I'm noticing that when I add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1, it breaks the `tel:` and `sms:` links I have in my `window.open()` on iOS and Android.

Here's the call I'm making from JS:

```
window.open(`sms:1231231234}`, '_self');
```

Here's how I have my access block set in the config.xml:

```
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="market:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms:*" />
<allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Here are the current plugins I'm using:

```
cordova-plugin-camera@2.4.1
cordova-plugin-console@1.0.7
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate@2.0.1
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.3.0
cordova-plugin-device@1.1.6
cordova-plugin-google-analytics@1.7.11
cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.3
cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.3
cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.2
ionic-plugin-keyboard@2.2.1
```

Any idea how to avoid this? All I need InAppBrowser is for opening an external webpage but I need my phone links to continue to work.

Comment: what happens if you window.open() a http:// url?

Comment: With InAppBrowser, that works as expected. It opens the site on the system browser (my target is `_system`).

Comment: sounds like inappbrowser takes over window.open().  you never set window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open  did you?

Comment: No, not that I'm aware of. I'm not sure if Ionic would have done that for me.

Comment: try doing a 'delete window.open' and see if the regular functionality returns. you'll then have to use cordova.inAppBrowser.open() per the docs to open external webpages. deleting window.open() should free it up for you to use it for sms and tel links. see https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

Comment: That didn't work either. Ended up just using Ionic's plugins for inappbrowser, phonedialer, sms, and email. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resorted to using these plugins to get it to work:

```
call-number@https://github.com/Rohfosho/CordovaCallNumberPlugin.git#7d6e87569b101a0abb3ba9259f17bfec0b1719d7
cordova-plugin-camera@2.4.1
cordova-plugin-console@1.0.7
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-certificate@2.0.1
cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview@2.3.0
cordova-plugin-device@1.1.6
cordova-plugin-email@1.2.6
cordova-plugin-google-analytics@1.7.11
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser@1.7.1
cordova-plugin-splashscreen@4.0.3
cordova-plugin-statusbar@2.2.3
cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.3.2
cordova-sms-plugin@0.1.11
ionic-plugin-keyboard@2.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding these to config file ?

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

This helped me.

Comment: I have something similar above. Adding the additional intents doesn't help.